# crash happened when I try to settitle of a UIButton instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

here i have a custom UITableViewcell which contains several UIButton added into its contentview as subview. after when i'd like to assign these UIButton's titlelabel in the UITableView, but crash happened.(But I can assign these button's action to catch event.)
Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];            
        for (UIView *subviews in cell.contentView.subviews)
        {
            CGRect r;
            UIButton *btttn = (UIButton *)[subviews viewWithTag:subviews.tag];
            switch (subviews.tag) {
                case 101: case 102: case 103: case 104: case 105: case 106: case 107:
                    subviews.layer.masksToBounds = NO ;
                    subviews.backgroundColor = [ UIColor whiteColor ];

                    //[btttn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];// Crash happened here!
                    [btttn addTarget:self action:@selector (OnWorkHourClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //This line works if without upper line.
                    r = subviews.frame;
                case 12:
                    subviews.layer.masksToBounds = NO ;
                    subviews.backgroundColor = [ UIColor whiteColor ];
                    [btttn addTarget:self action:@selector (OnJobAddClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    r = subviews.frame;
            }
        }
return cell;}
```

Comment: Crashes don't just happen.  XCode should have given you some details on the crash which will be helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: I'v tried to catch expection and it shows:[UITextField setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9097660

Comment: The exception tells you that you call `setTitile:forState` on a `UITextField` object which does not have such method. So you probably need to check the code where you want to set the title, see if the receiver is a `UIButton`

Comment: Yes, as Eric said one of the items you are casting to a UIButton (The btttn variable) is likely a UITextField not a UIButton. Is every subview of the cell content a button?

Comment: Opps!!I get your point!How stupid I am...!It's my fault! actually, subviews "was" contain a UIButton;however,I just change those UIButton as UITextfield for the needs of Demo purpose!!Thanks for all of your reminds!!